# [Ctrl][Alt] causing windows to maximise vertically

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcuts, maximized

Ubuntu 14.10, Unity, running Windows under KVM.  Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>immediately causes the focused window to maximise vertically (no other keys pressed).

Pressing them again causes the window to toggles between that and maximise in both dimensions.  A double click in the title bar maximises (if not already so), and another double click restores the window to its original dimensions.

I have found no binding for simply <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> in Settings→Keyboard→Shortcuts.
I also tried CompizConfig settings manager, found no references to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>

The output of

```
gsettings list-recursively | grep --ignore-case ctrl | grep --ignore-case alt
```

[can be found here.](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10177753/)

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-) Can you post the output of `gsettings list-recursively  | grep --ignore-case ctrl | grep --ignore-case alt` to http://paste.ubuntu.com and post the link you receive back into your question?  [Edit] your question first.

Comment: @Fabby i have the same problem , heres mine `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys window-screenshot-clip <Ctrl><Alt>Print
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys screencast <Ctrl> `<Shift><Alt>R
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys window-screenshot-clip '<Ctrl><Alt>Print'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys screencast <Ctrl><Shift><Alt>R
org.onboard.lockdown disable-keys [[CTRL', LALT, F[0-9]+]]
org.onboard.lockdown disable-keys [[CTRL', LALT, F[0-9]+]]`

Comment: I have no answer:  It's defined somewhere where I have no knowledge of...  Sorry

Comment: Start the command `find ~ -type f -maxdepth 2 -print0 -iname '.*'| xargs -0 grep -rIP 'Alt_(L|R)'` to check your configuration files and add the output into your question as an [edit]. After that give me a ping with @A.B. in the comments.

Answer (score -1):

Go to `settings` > `keyboard` > `shortcut tab` and create a new custom shortcut using these values:

`Name: [What ever you want]
Command: false
Shortcut: Ctrl+Alt`

Comment: You solves a problem with an other problem.

Comment: @A.B. It's the only way, and it worth it.

Comment: The only way is, to find the configuration for the shortcut.

Comment: @A.B. dude, trust me. there is no command registered with <control>+<alt> that I can find in my system. I searched all shortcuts in compiz. no luck in `gsettings list-recursively | grep --ignore-case ctrl | grep --ignore-case alt` either.

Comment: What do you think, how many ways there are to define shortcuts. You'd be amazed.